# How do I control anchor tags in CSS slider so it doesn't reposition scroll on page?

Tags: html, css, scroll, slider, anchor

I am attempting to create a CSS-only slider that I can use in more than one instance on a page. I've used anchor tags to control the scroll and the sliders work perfectly, but only in a vacuum.

Once they are placed on a page with content, clicking on the anchor (arrows) scrolls the page until that slider is at the top. This is unwanted behavior. Is there some way I can stop that from happening?

It also "resets" the other slider. So, for instance, if I have scrolled partially through the second slider, and then decide to scroll through the first one, the second slider goes back to the beginning. This is not as serious a problem as the first one, but if there were a simple fix, I'd love to know about it.

Here is a link to the test: http://nimbleforce.com/temp/slider/slider.html
And this is the CSS I'm using: http://nimbleforce.com/temp/slider/sliderStyle.css

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you wanted to make this CSS only, but would a `preventDefault` be out of the question?

```
$("a[href='#']").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Change the `"a[href='#']"` to a class selector if you find them more comfortable.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm not against jQuery, just terribly unfamiliar with it, so I tried this. When I used your code, nothing changed. When I simply used "a" rather than 'a[href='#']' the sliders stopped working entirely. It's up on the test site with your code. Did I insert it incorrectly?

Comment: Prevent default will strip out the default action that the anchor tags perform. You may need to add some additional lines above the preventDefault code. For example you may want to add a class of 'active' `.addClass('active')` and style this class accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your time on this. I'm so doggone ignorant about jQuery. I don't know how to style a new class to make the anchor work for slider scrolling while the preventDefault is in place to make that same link not function. I will play with it though. I appreciate the direction.

Comment: Not a problem, best of luck :)